# Do you gain your CON modifier per hit die that you spend during a rest?

Tags: dnd-5e, healing, hit-points

If your hit die is a d8 and your CON modifier is +2, do you:
Get **1d8+2 HP** restored per hit die during a rest, or **just 1d8 HP**?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

From the *Short Rest* section on page 186 of the PHB:

> For **each** Hit Die spent in this way, the player rolls the die and adds the character’s Constitution modifier to it. The character regains hit points equal to the total.

So yes, you add you Con mod to **each** hit die you spent during a short rest.